# Angular ng-repeat on array inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have problem accessing an array inside an array of objects in AngularJS.

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="ai in main.a2">
  <div np-repeat="bi in ai.b">
    <span ng-bind="bi"></span>b2
  </div>
 </li>
```

javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  self.a2 = [
    {b: ['foo']},
    {b: ['bar', 'baz']},
    {b: ['boo']}
 ];
}]);
```

Expected output:

```
foob2
foobazb2
boob2
```

Real output:

```
b2
b2
b2
```

And here is the (non-working) [example](http://plnkr.co/2GqMsuAD050RFqiV6Lj8).

I have checked similar posts, but most of them are just mistakes, and so could be mine. But I have checked with errors so I am thinking that I have fallen into some pitfall.

Comment: You have a typo: `np-repeat`, should be `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo error in `<div np-repeat="bi in ai.b">`. Change it to:

```
<div ng-repeat="bi in ai.b">
```

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.a2 = [
       {b: ['foo']},
       {b: ['bar', 'baz']},
       {b: ['boo']}
    ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <li ng-repeat="ai in a2">
       <div ng-repeat="bi in ai.b">
         <span ng-bind="bi"></span>b2
       </div>
   </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo like @Arg0n mentioned. `np-repeat`, should be `ng-repeat`.

And in-order to make this in line add `style="display:inline"`  style.

```
 <li ng-repeat="ai in main.a2">
    <div ng-repeat="bi in ai.b" style="display:inline">
      <span>{{bi}}</span>
    </div>b2
  </li>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0q596khsWPyKcdlX5oSy?p=preview)